# iTunes 9 Podcast Playorder

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I know that Apple seems to not think people want to do things easily, like how to [show exact duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/37488/what-is-the-best-free-way-to-remove-duplicate-files-from-itunes) or [play podcasts in order on the iPod from oldest to newest](http://www.macworld.com/article/61460/2007/12/oldpodcasttonew.html), but I can't seem to find how to play the podcasts from oldest to newest in iTunes itself.

I see posts and articles listing using the [smart playlist](https://superuser.com/questions/7827/is-there-a-way-to-get-itunes-to-automatically-play-all-items-in-a-podcast) but shouldn't there be an easier less cluttered way of doing this in iTunes 9? I like the current organization I have with only a few playlists of the songs I really enjoy and the podcasts for the mixes I listen to in traffic or at work.

Am I not pressing the keys in the right order, or is this something Apple hasn't corrected yet?

Comment: What is it you want to do?

Comment: I want to play the podcasts in order from oldest to newest, just like it does on the iPod.

Comment: The answer is in your question.  Create a smart playlist.

Comment: And I was hoping that wouldn't be it, there's not another way with the  new version of iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right - either a Smart Playlist, or sort your podcasts by date, then added them to your playlost in that order.

The second option is what I've been doing for several versions.

Comment: Do you know if Apple is planning to correct the play order?

Comment: no clue.. it'd be nice, but don't work for 'em, just use 'em :)